# Extracting value between single quotes if the value match

Tags: python

I have one line message as below and i have thousands of message like this:

```
FSD+123:523664543:4::TKFSD:62:1+20230811:123313589+62+20221203:181454957'VAI+I:KK+CH:421'MGA+S:SSSS+1+1+20230811'VAK+I:KKIIII+TKN:4+Crest Builder Hl Rg+Registered Shs'LRI+S:KK+TKN:1'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+23+1'FSR+S:KSSSSS+114+1'FSR+S:KSSSSS+118+1'FSL+S:K+R11'FSM+S:KSSSSS+R11I40+1++20220101++4'LRI+S:KK+TKN:572'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+23+1'LRI+S:KK+TKN:402'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+12+2+1'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+32+2+3++20160405'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+68+17'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'FSR+S:KSSSSS+170+2+100'FSL+S:K+M11'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M11I02+17++20210710++14'LRI+S:KK+TKN:369'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+12+10+25'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'FSR+S:KSSSSS+59+16++20191001'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'LRI+S:KK+TKN:814'LRI+S:KK+TKN:120'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+51+1+4+20180101'FST+S:KSSSSS+2+::,35::4'FSE+S:KSSSSSSS+70+1++20180101'LRI+S:KK+TKN:816'FSR+S:KSSSSS+27+3'FST+S:KSSSSS+3'FSL+S:K+M01'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M01SHRS+1++20170703++4'FSL+S:K+M11'FSM+M:KSSSSS+M11I09+16++20170703++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M11I01+17++20170902++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M11I02+17++20191109++4'FSL+S:K+M10'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M10C01+1++20200711++4'FSL+S:K+M21'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M21T01+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M21T02+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M21T03+16+41+20200711++4'FSL+S:K+M22'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M22T01+16+43+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M22T02+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M22T03+16+41+20200711++4'FSL+S:K+M23'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M23T03+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M23T04+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M23T01+16+42+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M23T02+16+43+20200711++4'FSL+S:K+M24'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M24T02+16+41+20200711++4'FSL+S:K+M25'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M25T06+16+43+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M25T08+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M25T07+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M25T10+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M25T11+16+41+20200711++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M25T05+16+41+20200711++4'FSN+S:KSSSSSSSSSS+M25T05V1++4++5+7+5'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M25T02+16+41+20200711++4'FSL+S:K+M27'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M27T01+16+41+20200711++4'FSN+S:KSSSSSSSSSS+M27T01V2++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M27T04+16+41+20200711++4'FSN+S:KSSSSSSSSSS+M27T04V3++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M27T02+16+41+20200711++4'FSN+S:KSSSSSSSSSS+M27T02V3++4'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M27T03+16+41+20200711++4'FSN+S:KSSSSSSSSSS+M27T03V3++4'FSL+S:K+R12'LRI+S:KK+TKN:44'FSL+S:K+M22'FSM+S:KSSSSS+M22T03+16+41+20200711++4'LRI+S:KK+TKN:470'FSL+S:K+R10'LRI+S:KK+TKN:594'xzch200327tap:20231006 10:11:56$
```

Single quote is a segment and I want to extract only 2 segments from the entire file of messages:

- '**VAI**+I:KK+CH:421' (VAI is the key here)
- '**FSM**+S:KSSSSS+**M11I02**+17++20210710++**14**'(FSM, M11I02 and 14 are the keys)

My output should be like below. I have millions of different messages and I just want to extract:

```
'VAI+I:KK+CH:421' FSM**+S:KSSSSS+M11I02+17++20210710++14'
```

Python script I used

```
import re

# Function to extract strings between single quotes that contain 'VAI' and 'M11I02'
def extract_strings_with_values(messages):
    result = []
    pattern = r"'(.*?)'"
    for message in messages:
        matches = re.findall(pattern, message)
        for match in matches:
            if 'VAI' in match and 'M11I02' in match:
                result.append(match)
    return result

# Read messages from a file (replace 'your_file.txt' with the actual file path)
file_path = 'filepath'

file = open(file_path, 'r')
lines = file.readlines()

# Strips the newline character
for messages in lines:
    print(messages)
    # Call the function to extract desired strings
    filtered_strings = extract_strings_with_values(messages)

# Print the extracted strings
for string in filtered_strings:
        print(string)
```

But this give me full result not the exact string, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You want to stop on `"14"` but your code has no provision for that. The rest of your code looks reasonable...

Comment: I was trying to get both 14 and 4, but nothing comes up either, i get entire output :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to match one of these regex:

- `'FSM.*M11I02.*14'`
- `'VAI.*'`

Here is the correct code

```
def extract_strings_with_values(messages):
    result = []
    
    # Define the regex patterns
    pattern1 = r"FSM.*M11I02.*14"
    pattern2 = r"VAI.*"
    
    # Split the message into segments using single quotes
    segments = messages.split("'")
    
    for segment in segments:
        # Check if the segment matches either of the regex patterns
        if re.match(pattern1, segment) or re.match(pattern2, segment):
            result.append(segment)
    
    return result
```

Comment: Perfect. thanks a lot